# MySQL AVG based on another column's value

Tags: mysql, average

I have the following Select statement where I am getting an average of a column

```
SELECT, tblTracks.*, AVG(tblTrackRatings.intRating) AS dblAverageRating,......
```

This is working fine, however, I would like to be able to get an average of only those ratings who have another column (bolDeleted) set to 0.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try:

```
WHERE bolDeleted = 0;
```